# Is there a better way to guess possible unknown variables without brute force than I am doing? Machine learning?

Tags: python, algorithm, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a game with the following rules:

- A user is given fruit prices and has a chance to buy or sell items in their fruit basket every turn.
- The user cannot make more than a 10% total change in their basket on a single turn.
- Fruit prices change every day and when multiplied by the quantities of items in the fruit basket, the total value of the basket changes relative to the fruit price changes every day as well.
- The program is only given the current price of all the fruits and the current value of the basket (current price of fruit * quantities for all items in the basket).
- Based on these 2 inputs(all fruit prices and basket total value), the program tries to guess what items are in the basket.
- A basket cannot hold more than 100 items but slots can be empty
- The player can play several turns.

My goal is to accurately guess as computationally inexpensively as possible (read: no brute force) and scale if there are thousands of new fruits.

I am struggling to find an answer but in my mind, it’s not hard. If I have the below table.  I could study day 1 and get the following data:

```
Apple   1
Pears   2
Oranges 3

Basket Value = 217
```

I can do a back of napkin calculation and assume, the weights in the basket are: 0 apple, 83 pears, and 17 Oranges equaling a basket value of 217.

The next day, the values of the fruits and basket changes.  To (apple = 2, Pear 3, Oranges 5) with a basket value of 348.   When I take my assumed weights above (0,83,17) I get a total value of 334 – not correct!  Running this by my script, I see the closest match is 0 apples, 76 pears, 24 oranges which although does equal 348 when % change of factored in it’s a 38% change so it’s not possible!

I know I can completely brute force this but if I have 1000 fruits, it won’t scale. Not to jump on any bandwagon but can something like a neural net quickly rule out the unlikely so I calculate large volumes of data? I think they have to be a more scalable/quicker way than pure brute force? Or is there any other type of solution that could get the result?

Here is the raw data (remember program can only see prices and total basket value only):

[image]

Here's some brute force code (Thank you @paul Hankin for a cleaner example than mine):

```
def possibilities(value, prices):
    for i in range(0, value+1, prices[0]):
        for j in range(0, value+1-i, prices[1]):
            k = value - i - j
            if k % prices[2] == 0:
                yield i//prices[0], j//prices[1], k//prices[2]

def merge_totals(last, this, r):
    ok = []
    for t in this:
        for l in last:
            f = int(sum(l) * r)
            if all(l[i] -f <= t[i] <= l[i] + f for i in range(len(l))):
                ok.append(t)
                break
    return ok

days = [
    (217, (1, 2, 3)),
    (348, (2, 3, 5)),
    (251, (1, 2, 4)),
]

ps = None
for i, d in enumerate(days):
    new_ps = list(possibilities(*d))
    if ps is None:
        ps = new_ps
    ps = merge_totals(ps, new_ps, 0.10)

    print('Day %d' % (i+1))
    for p in ps:
        print('Day %d,' % (i+1), 'apples: %s, pears: %s, oranges: %s' % p)
    print
```

**Update** - The info so far is awesome. Does it make sense to break the problem into two problems? One is generating the possibilities while the other is finding the relationship between the possibilities(no more than a 10% daily change).  By ruling out possibilities, couldn't that also be used to help only generate possibilities that are possible, to begin with? I'm not sure the approach still but I do feel both problems are different but tightly related. Your thoughts?

**Update 2** - there are a lot of questions about the % change.  This is the total volume of items in the basket that can change.  To use the game example, Imagine the store says - you can sell/return/buy fruits but they cannot be more than 10% of your last bill.  So although the change in fruit prices can cause changes in your basket value, the user cannot take any action that would impact it by more than 10%. So if the value was 100, they can make changes that create get it to 110 but not more.

Comment: It doesn't seem likely that you can come up with a deterministic algorithm. There are too many variables. If the numbers of the fruits can change without bound so long as the price doesn't change more than x%, the user can almost certainly come up with a price that can be reached by at least two different combinations. That's especially true as the difference between the minimum individual fruit price and the total package price increases.

Comment: @JimMischel Thank you - I’m not sure I understand your comment correctly.  The user does not have control of the price, only the quantity of fruits and the program only see’s the total value of the basket and current price of fruit.   I think predicting this on the first try is not possible but over time (say the player plays 50 times) I believe a pattern should emerge as the user’s quantity changes are bounded and changes in price of fruits over time could narrow down the quantities.  Remember because the quantity cannot change more than 5%, there is a connection to previous baskets.

Comment: Does the user know the individual fruit prices when he's filling his basket?

Comment: @JimMischel yes, it’s displayed.

Comment: Then the user can potentially use that information to help him create a value that is reachable by at least two different combinations of fruit, thereby making it impossible for you to create a deterministic algorithm.

Comment: @JimMischel that’s fair but I do not think the user is trying to beat this process. They are simply just buying fruits based on their needs.  Also, if they were trying to beat the algo, they cannot change the quantity by more than 5% which, if the price moves a lot, would restrict their options.

Comment: If the prices do *not* change, then after 3 days, the computer can solve a 3-equations-3-unknowns problem and calculate exactly how many they've bought on each of the three days (no matter how much or how little they buy each day—barring pathological problems like they bought the same amounts each day, making a rank-deficient matrix). So the crucial complication is that prices are changing?

Comment: You can greatly increase the speed of your algorithm: the number of oranges is determined by the prices, number of apples, pears and total value, so you don't need to iterate over every possible value.

Comment: How large are the actual numbers in the game?

Comment: @PaulHankin that is what I did but it doesn’t scale with large items. Regarding numbers price can be anything but quantity can be limited (basket size can be limited).

Comment: @AhmedFasih interesting.  I thought the change in prices actually helped narrow down the possibles since over time it would rule out certain baskets quantities.

Comment: Can you provide a realistic example with actual numbers? Exactly how many types of items there are, the size of the basket, realistic prices, total price. You claim you can't brute force a solution, but it seems like you've based that on the fact that your code is too slow.

Comment: @PaulHankin This is a realistic. Basically prices are generated randomly and basket is user inputted (no more than 5% change from previous).  To make the example simple, I have 3 fruits but the solutions fail if there is 1000 fruits and the person chooses one of each. Bruce force at that point is not realistic.  If it helps, I can update the example and add 50 more fruits so show this flaw, but I thought it would take away from keeping the example simple for people to understand.  Totally happy to update the example.

Comment: This looks a run-of-the-mill *n* variables in *m* equations problem but for the `10% total change in [the] basket` restriction - which needs specification: one tenth change *of what*? How is the `38% change` in the example computed? What is the goal of 1) the game 2) your question on SO?

Comment: machine learning is about finding patterns. If prices are truly random theres no pattern to learn.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the way that the daily total % change in the basket is calculated is this: get the relative change for each of the three fruits from day `n-1` to day `n`, then sum over these three values. For example, you end up adding x% change in apples to a y% change in oranges - isn't that literally comparing apples to oranges? Furthermore, if you ever have a quantity of a type of fruit of less than 10, you could never change that because you would immediately hit the 10% restriction. Or am I completely wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand the problem, specifically that user can buy/sell fruits each day. I assume the program cannot control those transactions- but is the program told about the transaction - or does it have to infer the transactions as well? Can there be more than one turn per day?

Comment: @HansOlsson the point of the game is to infer the transactions based only on the knowledge of the price change of fruits, basket capacity(100 in this care) and value of basket.

Comment: @WolfgangK that is correct except it's 10% change of total basket value not individual fruit changes. You can make a 100% change on a fruit as long as the total basket is within the 10% range still.

Comment: I still think that the problem is insufficiently specified. As written, with no restrictions on the price changes and number of fruits, the problem is either trivially easy or there is no deterministic solution. The stipulation that "I don't think the user is trying to beat this process" is meaningless. The combination of price changes and user actions *could* produce a worst case.

Comment: @JimMischel that's correct but overtime factoring the price changes and  basket value, can it not be possible to have highly probable basket configurations?  I mean, even google first result isn't perfect but often the best options are on page 1 and they self improve.

Comment: The question **still** doesn't show what `% change` is supposed to mean. From deleted contents, it started with *total **count** of fruits*; comments recently mentioned `total basket value` - please specify *in the question proper*.

Comment: In your sample case, you assume that there are 0 apples, 83 pears and 17 oranges. Then, in the next round, you realise that this assumption must be incorrect. The main reason his happens is that it's *very* unlikely that you'll assume correctly; in your sample case, there are **616** possible combinations for your basket. Naturally, this means that assuming that you've guessed it correctly is an assumption unlikely to be true.

Comment: @greybeard I updated the question(see update 2). Does that make it more clear?

Comment: I do not see how having rules about *prices*, *% total ("user") change* and *quantities* does improve by introducing another notion, *volume*. Rather explain how going from `217` to `348` does *not* conflict with the 10 % change limit.

Comment: @greybeard the driver of the change is price of fruit change from 217 to 348. The limit is imposed of the driver is a user driven change such as quantity of fruits in basket.

Comment: Silly point, but aren't your % change calculations in your table image incorrect? For example, when going from day 1 to day 2 apples (i.e. 20 -> 21 apples), it appears you do abs(21 - 20)/21 * 100 to get 4.76%, but wouldn't it be (21 - 20)/20 * 100 = 5%? That is, the % change should be calculated by taking the absolute value of the delta divided by the old number rather than the new number.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon agh your right. My mistake

Comment: this question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366811/what-to-do-when-a-user-reposts-their-own-question-possibly-for-reputation)

Comment: Actually, this is a duplicate of lots of posts ... see the meta discussion

Answer (score 27):

I hate to let you down but I really don't think a neural net will help at all for this problem, and IMO the best answer to your question is the advice "don't waste your time trying neural nets".

An easy rule of thumb for deciding whether or not neural networks are applicable is to think, "can an average adult human solve this problem reasonably well in a few seconds?" For problems like "what's in this image", "respond to this question", or "transcribe this audio clip", the answer is *yes*. But for your problem, the answer is a most definite *no*.

Neural networks have limitations, and one is that they don't deal well with highly logical problems. This is because the answers are generally not "smooth". If you take an image and slightly change a handful of pixels, the content of the image is still the same. If you take an audio clip and insert a few milliseconds of noise, a neural net will probably still be able to figure out what's said. But in your problem, change a single day's "total basket value" by only 1 unit, and your answer(s) will drastically change.

It seems that the only way to solve your problem is with a "classical" algorithmic approach. As currently stated, there might not be any algorithm better than brute force, and it might not be possible to rule out much. For example, what if every day has the property that all fruits are priced the same? The count of each fruit can vary, as long as the total number of fruits is fixed, so the number of possibilities is still exponential in the number of fruits. If your goal is to "produce a list of possibilities", then no algorithm can be better than exponential time since this list can be exponentially large in some cases.

It's interesting that part of your problem can be reduced to an [integer linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) (ILP). Consider a single day, where you are given the basket total `B` and each fruit's cost `c_i`, for `i=1` through `i=n` (if `n` is the total number of distinct fruits). Let's say the prices are large, so it's not obvious that you can "fill up" the basket with unit cost fruits. It can be hard in this situation to even find a single solution. Formulated as an ILP, this is equivalent to finding integer values of `x_i` such that:

```
sum_i (x_i*c_i) = x_1*c_1 + x_2*c_2 + ... + x_n*c_n = B
```

and `x_i >= 0` for all `1 <= i <= n` (can't have negative fruits), and `sum_i x_i <= 100` (can have at most 100 fruits).

The good news is that decent ILP solvers exist -- you can just hand over the above formulas and the solver will do its best to find a single solution. You can even add an "objective function" that the solver will maximize or minimize -- minimizing `sum_i x_i` has the effect of minimizing the total number of fruits in the basket. The bad news is that ILP is NP-complete, so there is almost no hope of finding an efficient solution for a large number of fruits (which equals the number of variables `x_i`).

I think the best approach forward is to try the ILP approach, but also introduce some more constraints on the scenario. For example, what if all fruits had a different prime number cost? This has the nice property that if you find one solution, you can enumerate a bunch of other related solutions. If an apple costs `m` and an orange costs `n`, where `m` and `n` are relatively prime, then you can "trade" `n*x` apples for `m*x` oranges without changing the basket total, for any integer `x>0` (so long as you have enough apples and oranges to begin with). If you choose all fruits to have different prime number costs, then all of the costs will be pairwise relatively prime. I think this approach will result in relatively few solutions for a given day.

You might also consider other constraints, such as "there can't be more than 5 fruits of a single kind in the basket" (add the constraint `x_i <= 5`), or "there can be at most 5 distinct kinds of fruits in the basket" (but this is harder to encode as an ILP constraint). Adding these kinds of constraints will make it easier for the ILP solver to find a solution.

Of course the above discussion is focused on a single day, and you have multiple days' worth of data. If the hardest part of the problem is finding any solution for any day at all (which happens if your prices are large), then using an ILP solver will give you a large boost. If solutions are easy to find (which happens if you have a very-low-cost fruit that can "fill up" your basket), and the hardest part of the problem is finding solutions that are "consistent" across multiple days, then the ILP approach might not be the best fit, and in general this problem seems much more difficult to reason about.

Edit: and as mentioned in the comments, for some interpretations of the "10% change" constraint, you can even encode the entire multi-day problem as an ILP.

Comment: I was going to suggest ILP, but you beat me to it. You can certainly code the 10% change as an inequality in the ILP: if `x_{d,i}` is the number of fruits of type i on day d, then x_{d+1,i} >= x_{d,i} - sum(x_{d,j} j=1..n)*0.1 and x_{d+1,i} <= x_{d,i} + sum(x_{d,j}, j=1..n).

Comment: "There can't be more than 5 distinct fruits" is easily encodable in the ILP. Let b_i be [0, 1] integer variables, and have the inequalities: b_i <= x_i, b_i >= x_i/1000 (where 1000 is any number larger than the size of the basket), then b_i is 0 if x_i is 0, and 1 if x_i isn't zero. Then you can add the constraint sum(b_i) <= 5.

Comment: (My guess is that with the problem as stated, with lots of fruits with realistic prices and multiple days, most of the time there's either a _lot_ of solutions or none and the ILP will quickly determine this).

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling the multi-day problem is ILP, but I wasn't sure what "10% change" precisely meant. I have no idea how the OP computed 38% in the example...

Comment: Oh it seems |76-83|/76 + |24-17|/24 approx 38%...

Comment: Yes, and that's not the interpretation I had above. Not sure if this is encodable into the ILP.

Comment: @Lostsoul I'm not sure how familiar you are with ILP. If you need, ping me and I can edit in a more detailed writeup of the multi-day problem as an ILP.

Comment: Thank you for the great reply.  For the problem being highly logical and not smooth, I think for daily changes this is true but overtime because of the movement of price of fruits, 10% change restriction & limited basket size, I believe over time(50+ turns) a pattern would emerge that is similar to your audio/picture example.  It’s my theory by doing this calculation in excel by hand.

Comment: also if you need any clarification or anything isn't unclear don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: In general, if there is a "classical" approach to a problem (in this case, the multi-day ILP approach), 99% of the time it's going to be better than a neural net.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me like your approach is reasonable, but whether it is depends on the size of the numbers in the actual game. Here's a complete implementation that's a lot more efficient than yours (but still has plenty of scope for improvement). It keeps a list of possibilities for the previous day, and then filters the current day amounts to those that are within 5% of some possibility from the previous day, and prints them out per day.

```
def possibilities(value, prices):
    for i in range(0, value+1, prices[0]):
        for j in range(0, value+1-i, prices[1]):
            k = value - i - j
            if k % prices[2] == 0:
                yield i//prices[0], j//prices[1], k//prices[2]

def merge_totals(last, this, r):
    ok = []
    for t in this:
        for l in last:
            f = int(sum(l) * r)
            if all(l[i] -f <= t[i] <= l[i] + f for i in range(len(l))):
                ok.append(t)
                break
    return ok

days = [
    (26, (1, 2, 3)),
    (51, (2, 3, 4)),
    (61, (2, 4, 5)),
]

ps = None
for i, d in enumerate(days):
    new_ps = list(possibilities(*d))
    if ps is None:
        ps = new_ps
    ps = merge_totals(ps, new_ps, 0.05)

    print('Day %d' % (i+1))
    for p in ps:
        print('apples: %s, pears: %s, oranges: %s' % p)
    print
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Paul. I updated the question to hopefully make it more clear.  This is a good implementation but I don't think it will work if there are 1k or 10k fruits.  Ideally there is a way to have the system intelligently narrow down the possibilities instead of pure brute force. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## Problem Framing

This problem can be described as a [combinatorial optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization).  You're trying to find an optimal object (a combination of fruit items) from a finite set of objects (all possible combinations of fruit items).  With the proper analogy and transformations, we can reduce this fruit basket problem to the well known, and extensively studied (since 1897), [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Solving this class of optimization problems is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness).  The decision problem of answering *"Can we find a combination of fruit items with a value of X?"* is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness).  Since you want to account for a worst case scenario when you have thousands of fruit items, your best bet is to use a [metaheuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic), like [evolutionary computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_computation).

## Proposed Solution

[Evolutionary computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_computation) is a family of biologically inspired metaheuristics.  They work by revising and mixing (evolving) the most fit candidate solutions based on a fitness function and discarding the least fit ones over many iterations.  The higher the fitness of a solution, the more likely it will reproduce similar solutions and survive to the next generation (iteration).  Eventually, a local or global optimal solution is found.

These methods provide a needed compromise when the search space is too large to cover with traditional closed form mathematical solutions.  Due to the stochastic nature of these algorithms, different executions of the algorithms may lead to different local optima, and there is no guarantee that the global optimum will be found.  The odds are good in our case since we have multiple valid solutions.

## Example

Let's use the [Distributed Evolutionary Algorithms in Python (DEAP)](https://github.com/DEAP/deap)  framework and retrofit their [Knapsack problem example](https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/examples/ga/knapsack.py) to our problem.  In the code below we apply strong penalty for baskets with 100+ items.  This will severely reduce their fitness and have them taken out of the population pool in one or two generations.  There are [other ways to handle constraints](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/dev/tutorials/advanced/constraints.html) that are also valid.

```
#    This file is part of DEAP.
#
#    DEAP is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
#    published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of
#    the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#    DEAP is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
#    GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
#    License along with DEAP. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

import random

import numpy as np

from deap import algorithms
from deap import base
from deap import creator
from deap import tools

IND_INIT_SIZE = 5 # Calls to `individual` function
MAX_ITEM = 100   # Max 100 fruit items in basket
NBR_ITEMS = 50   # Start with 50 items in basket
FRUIT_TYPES = 10 # Number of fruit types (apples, bananas, ...)

# Generate a dictionary of random fruit prices.
fruit_price = {i: random.randint(1, 5)  for i in range(FRUIT_TYPES)}

# Create fruit items dictionary.  The key is item ID, and the 
# value is a (weight, price) tuple.  Weight is always 1 here.
items = {}
# Create random items and store them in the items' dictionary.
for i in range(NBR_ITEMS):
    items[i] = (1, fruit_price[i])

# Create fitness function and an individual (solution candidate)
# A solution candidate in our case is a collection of fruit items.
creator.create("Fitness", base.Fitness, weights=(-1.0, 1.0))
creator.create("Individual", set, fitness=creator.Fitness)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()

# Randomly initialize the population (a set of candidate solutions)
toolbox.register("attr_item", random.randrange, NBR_ITEMS)
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, 
toolbox.attr_item, IND_INIT_SIZE)


def evalBasket(individual):
    """Evaluate the value of the basket and
    apply constraints penalty.
    """
    value = 0 # Total value of the basket
    for item in individual:
        value += items[item][1]

    # Heavily penalize baskets with 100+ items
    if len(individual) > MAX_ITEM:
        return 10000, 0
    return len(individual), value  # (items in basket, value of basket)


def cxSet(ind1, ind2):
    """Apply a crossover operation on input sets.
    The first child is the intersection of the two sets,
    the second child is the difference of the two sets.
    This is one way to evolve new candidate solutions from
    existing ones.  Think of it as parents mixing their genes
    to produce a child.
    """
    temp = set(ind1)                # Used in order to keep type
    ind1 &= ind2                    # Intersection (inplace)
    ind2 ^= temp                    # Symmetric Difference (inplace)
    return ind1, ind2


def mutSet(individual):
    """Mutation that pops or add an element.
    In nature, gene mutations help offspring express new traits
    not found in their ancestors.  That could be beneficial or 
    harmful.  Survival of the fittest at play here.
    """
    if random.random() < 0.5:  # 50% chance of mutation
        if len(individual) > 0:
            individual.remove(random.choice(sorted(tuple(individual))))
    else:
        individual.add(random.randrange(NBR_ITEMS))
    return individual,

# Register evaluation, mating, mutation and selection functions
# so the framework can use them to run the simulation.
toolbox.register("evaluate", evalKnapsack)
toolbox.register("mate", cxSet)
toolbox.register("mutate", mutSet)
toolbox.register("select", tools.selNSGA2)


def main():
    random.seed(64)
    NGEN = 50
    MU = 50
    LAMBDA = 100
    CXPB = 0.7
    MUTPB = 0.2

    pop = toolbox.population(n=MU)  # Initial population size
    hof = tools.ParetoFront()    # Using Pareto front to rank fitness

    # Keep track of population fitness stats which should 
    # improve over generations (iterations).
    stats = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
    stats.register("avg", numpy.mean, axis=0)
    stats.register("std", numpy.std, axis=0)
    stats.register("min", numpy.min, axis=0)
    stats.register("max", numpy.max, axis=0)

    algorithms.eaMuPlusLambda(pop, toolbox, MU,LAMBDA,\
                              CXPB, MUTPB, NGEN, stats,\
                              halloffame=hof)
    return pop, stats, hof


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: One thing to note.  This code is hard seeded to maintain less variance in the output.

Answer (score 5):

## Integer Linear Programming Approach

This sets up naturally as a multi-step Integer Program, with the holdings in {apples, pears, oranges} from the previous step factoring in the calculation of the relative change in holdings that must be constrained. There is no notion of optimal here, but we can turn the "turnover" constraint into an objective and see what happens.

**The solutions provided improve on those in your chart above, and are minimal in the sense of total change in basket holdings.**

Comments -

- I don't know how you calculated the "% change" column in your table. A change from Day 1 to Day 2 of 20 apples to 21 apples is a 4.76% change?
- On all days, your total holdings in fruits is exactly 100. There is a constraint that the sum of holdings is <= 100. No violation, I just want to confirm.

We can set this up as an integer linear program, using the integer optimization routine from `ortools`. I haven't used an ILP solver for a long time, and this one is kind of flaky I think (the solver.OPTIMAL flag is *never* true it seems, even for toy problems. In addition the `ortools` LP solver fails to find an optimal solution in cases where `scipy.linprog` works without a hitch)

```
h1,d = holdings in apples (number of apples) at end of day d
h2,d = holdings in pears at end of day d
h3,d = holdings in oranges at end of day d
```

I'll give two proposals here, one which minimizes the `l1` norm of the absolute error, the other the `l0`norm.

The `l1` solution finds the minimum of `abs(h1,(d+1) - h1,d)/h1 + ... + abs(h3,(d+1) - h3,d)/h3)`, hoping that the constraint that each relative change in holdings is under 10% if the sum of the relative change in holdings is minimized.

The only thing that prevents this from being a linear program (aside from the integer requirement) is the nonlinear objective function. No problem, we can introduce slack variables and make everything linear. For the `l1` formulation, 6 additional slack variables are introduced, 2 per fruit, and 6 additional inequality constraints. For the `l0` formulation, 1 slack variable is introduced, and 6 additional inequality constraints.

This is a two step process, for example, replacing |apples_new - apples_old|/|apples_old| with the variable |e|, and adding inequality constraints to ensure the e measures what we'd like. We then replace|e| with (e+ - e-), each of e+, e- >0. It can be shown that one of e+, e- will be 0, and that (e+ + e-) is the absolute value of e. That way the pair (e+, e-) can represent a positive or negative number. Standard stuff, but that adds a bunch of variables and constraints. I can explain this in a bit more detail if necessary.

```
import numpy as np
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp


def fruit_basket_l1_ortools():

    UPPER_BOUND = 1000

    prices = [[2,3,5],
              [1,2,4],
              [1,2,3]]

    holdings = [20,43,37]

    values = [348, 251, 213]

    for day in range(len(values)):

        solver = pywraplp.Solver('ILPSolver',
                                  pywraplp.Solver.BOP_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)
        # solver = pywraplp.Solver('ILPSolver',
        #                          pywraplp.Solver.CLP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)


        c = ([1,1] * 3) + [0,0,0]

        price = prices[day]
        value = values[day]

        A_eq = [[ 0,  0, 0,  0, 0,  0, price[0], price[1], price[2]]]

        b_eq = [value]

        A_ub = [[-1*holdings[0], 1*holdings[0],              0,             0,              0,              0,  1.0,    0,    0],
                [-1*holdings[0], 1*holdings[0],              0,             0,              0,              0, -1.0,    0,    0],
                [             0,             0, -1*holdings[1], 1*holdings[1],              0,              0,    0,  1.0,    0],
                [             0,             0, -1*holdings[1], 1*holdings[1],              0,              0,    0, -1.0,    0],
                [             0,             0,              0,              0, -1*holdings[2], 1*holdings[2],    0,    0,  1.0],
                [             0,             0,              0,              0, -1*holdings[2], 1*holdings[2],    0,    0, -1.0]]

        b_ub = [1*holdings[0], -1*holdings[0], 1*holdings[1], -1*holdings[1], 1*holdings[2], -1*holdings[2]]

        num_vars             = len(c)
        num_ineq_constraints = len(A_ub)
        num_eq_constraints   = len(A_eq)                

        data = [[]] * num_vars

        data[0]  = solver.IntVar(           0, UPPER_BOUND, 'e1_p')
        data[1]  = solver.IntVar(           0, UPPER_BOUND, 'e1_n')
        data[2]  = solver.IntVar(           0, UPPER_BOUND, 'e2_p')
        data[3]  = solver.IntVar(           0, UPPER_BOUND, 'e2_n')
        data[4]  = solver.IntVar(           0, UPPER_BOUND, 'e3_p')
        data[5]  = solver.IntVar(           0, UPPER_BOUND, 'e3_n')
        data[6]  = solver.IntVar(           0, UPPER_BOUND, 'x1')
        data[7]  = solver.IntVar(           0, UPPER_BOUND, 'x2')
        data[8]  = solver.IntVar(           0, UPPER_BOUND, 'x3')

        constraints = [0] * (len(A_ub) + len(b_eq))

        # Inequality constraints
        for i in range(0,num_ineq_constraints):
            constraints[i] = solver.Constraint(-solver.infinity(), b_ub[i])
            for j in range(0,num_vars):
                constraints[i].SetCoefficient(data[j], A_ub[i][j])

        # Equality constraints
        for i in range(num_ineq_constraints, num_ineq_constraints+num_eq_constraints):
            constraints[i] = solver.Constraint(b_eq[i-num_ineq_constraints], b_eq[i-num_ineq_constraints])
            for j in range(0,num_vars):
                constraints[i].SetCoefficient(data[j], A_eq[i-num_ineq_constraints][j])

        # Objective function
        objective = solver.Objective()
        for i in range(0,num_vars):
            objective.SetCoefficient(data[i], c[i])

        # Set up as minization problem
        objective.SetMinimization()

        # Solve it
        result_status = solver.Solve()

        solution_set = [data[i].solution_value() for i in range(len(data))]

        print('DAY: {}'.format(day+1))
        print('======')
        print('SOLUTION FEASIBLE: {}'.format(solver.FEASIBLE))
        print('SOLUTION OPTIMAL:  {}'.format(solver.OPTIMAL))
        print('VALUE OF BASKET:   {}'.format(np.dot(A_eq[0], solution_set)))
        print('SOLUTION   (apples,pears,oranges): {!r}'.format(solution_set[-3:]))
        print('PCT CHANGE (apples,pears,oranges): {!r}\n\n'.format([round(100*(x-y)/y,2) for x,y in zip(solution_set[-3:], holdings)]))

        # Update holdings for the next day
        holdings = solution_set[-3:]
```

A single run gives:

```
DAY: 1
======
SOLUTION FEASIBLE: 1
SOLUTION OPTIMAL:  0
VALUE OF BASKET:   348.0
SOLUTION   (apples,pears,oranges): [20.0, 41.0, 37.0]
PCT CHANGE (apples,pears,oranges): [0.0, -4.65, 0.0]


DAY: 2
======
SOLUTION FEASIBLE: 1
SOLUTION OPTIMAL:  0
VALUE OF BASKET:   251.0
SOLUTION   (apples,pears,oranges): [21.0, 41.0, 37.0]
PCT CHANGE (apples,pears,oranges): [5.0, 0.0, 0.0]


DAY: 3
======
SOLUTION FEASIBLE: 1
SOLUTION OPTIMAL:  0
VALUE OF BASKET:   213.0
SOLUTION   (apples,pears,oranges): [20.0, 41.0, 37.0]
PCT CHANGE (apples,pears,oranges): [-4.76, 0.0, 0.0]
```

The `l0` formulation is also presented:

```
def fruit_basket_l0_ortools():

    UPPER_BOUND = 1000

    prices = [[2,3,5],
              [1,2,4],
              [1,2,3]]

    holdings = [20,43,37]

    values = [348, 251, 213]

    for day in range(len(values)):

        solver = pywraplp.Solver('ILPSolver',
                                  pywraplp.Solver.BOP_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)
        # solver = pywraplp.Solver('ILPSolver',
        #                          pywraplp.Solver.CLP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)

        c = [1, 0, 0, 0]

        price = prices[day]
        value = values[day]

        A_eq = [[0, price[0], price[1], price[2]]]

        b_eq = [value]

        A_ub = [[-1*holdings[0],  1.0,    0,    0],
                [-1*holdings[0], -1.0,    0,    0],
                [-1*holdings[1],    0,  1.0,    0],
                [-1*holdings[1],    0, -1.0,    0],
                [-1*holdings[2],    0,    0,  1.0],
                [-1*holdings[2],    0,    0, -1.0]]


        b_ub = [holdings[0], -1*holdings[0], holdings[1], -1*holdings[1], holdings[2], -1*holdings[2]]


        num_vars             = len(c)
        num_ineq_constraints = len(A_ub)
        num_eq_constraints   = len(A_eq)                

        data = [[]] * num_vars

        data[0]  = solver.IntVar(-UPPER_BOUND, UPPER_BOUND, 'e' )
        data[1]  = solver.IntVar(           0, UPPER_BOUND, 'x1')
        data[2]  = solver.IntVar(           0, UPPER_BOUND, 'x2')
        data[3]  = solver.IntVar(           0, UPPER_BOUND, 'x3')

        constraints = [0] * (len(A_ub) + len(b_eq))

        # Inequality constraints
        for i in range(0,num_ineq_constraints):
            constraints[i] = solver.Constraint(-solver.infinity(), b_ub[i])
            for j in range(0,num_vars):
                constraints[i].SetCoefficient(data[j], A_ub[i][j])

        # Equality constraints
        for i in range(num_ineq_constraints, num_ineq_constraints+num_eq_constraints):
            constraints[i] = solver.Constraint(int(b_eq[i-num_ineq_constraints]), b_eq[i-num_ineq_constraints])
            for j in range(0,num_vars):
                constraints[i].SetCoefficient(data[j], A_eq[i-num_ineq_constraints][j])

        # Objective function
        objective = solver.Objective()
        for i in range(0,num_vars):
            objective.SetCoefficient(data[i], c[i])

        # Set up as minization problem
        objective.SetMinimization()

        # Solve it
        result_status = solver.Solve()

        solution_set = [data[i].solution_value() for i in range(len(data))]

        print('DAY: {}'.format(day+1))
        print('======')
        print('SOLUTION FEASIBLE: {}'.format(solver.FEASIBLE))
        print('SOLUTION OPTIMAL:  {}'.format(solver.OPTIMAL))
        print('VALUE OF BASKET:   {}'.format(np.dot(A_eq[0], solution_set)))
        print('SOLUTION   (apples,pears,oranges): {!r}'.format(solution_set[-3:]))
        print('PCT CHANGE (apples,pears,oranges): {!r}\n\n'.format([round(100*(x-y)/y,2) for x,y in zip(solution_set[-3:], holdings)]))

        # Update holdings for the next day
        holdings = solution_set[-3:]
```

A single run of this gives

```
DAY: 1
======
SOLUTION FEASIBLE: 1
SOLUTION OPTIMAL:  0
VALUE OF BASKET:   348.0
SOLUTION   (apples,pears,oranges): [33.0, 79.0, 9.0]
PCT CHANGE (apples,pears,oranges): [65.0, 83.72, -75.68]


DAY: 2
======
SOLUTION FEASIBLE: 1
SOLUTION OPTIMAL:  0
VALUE OF BASKET:   251.0
SOLUTION   (apples,pears,oranges): [49.0, 83.0, 9.0]
PCT CHANGE (apples,pears,oranges): [48.48, 5.06, 0.0]


DAY: 3
======
SOLUTION FEASIBLE: 1
SOLUTION OPTIMAL:  0
VALUE OF BASKET:   213.0
SOLUTION   (apples,pears,oranges): [51.0, 63.0, 12.0]
PCT CHANGE (apples,pears,oranges): [4.08, -24.1, 33.33]
```

## Summary

The `l1` formulation gives more sensible results, lower turnover, much lower. The optimality check fails on all runs, however, which is concerning. I included a linear solver too and that fails the feasiblity check somehow, I don't know why. The Google people provide precious little documentation for the ortools lib, and most of it is for the C++ lib. But the `l1` formulation may be a solution to your problem, which may scale. ILP is in general NP-complete, and so is your problem most likely.

Also - does a solution exist on day 2? How do you define % change so that it does in your chart above? If I knew I could recast the inequalities above and we would have the general solution.

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer, but an attempt to make the one information about what "% change" might be supposed to mean (sum of change in count of each item *computed backwards*) more accessible to non-believers in pixel heaps:

> ```
>        | Day 1        ! Day 2   change      ! Day 3   change      ! Day 4   change
>        |$/1|  # |  $  !$/1|  # |   %  |  $  !$/1|  # |   %  |  $  !$/1|  # |   %  |  $
> Apples | 1 | 20 |  20 ! 2 | 21 | 4.76 |  42 ! 1 | 21 |  0   |  21 ! 1 | 22 | 4.55 |  22
> Pears  | 2 | 43 |  86 ! 3 | 42 | 2.38 | 126 ! 2 | 43 | 2.33 |  86 ! 2 | 43 |  0   |  86
> Oranges| 3 | 37 | 111 ! 5 | 36 | 2.78 | 180 ! 4 | 36 |  0   | 144 ! 3 | 35 | 2.86 | 105
> Total  |    100 | 217 !    100 | 9.92 | 348 !    100 | 2.33 | 251 !    100 | 7.40 | 213
> ```

Comment: For a solution, I might look into *range arithmetic* - if an when the problem was well defined.

Comment: This is a good re-format for the data. btw the OP commented that the backwards computation was a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

You got a **logic problem on integers, not a representation problem**. Neural networks are relevant to problem with complex representation (eg., image with pixels, objects in differents shape and color, sometimes hidden etc), as they build their own set of features (descriptors) and mipmaps; they also are a good match with problems dealing with reals, not integer; and last, as they are today, they don't really deal with reasonning and logic, or eventually with simple logic like a small succession of `if/else` or `switch` but we don't really have a control over that.

**What I see is closer to a cryptographic-ish problem with constraints (10% change, max 100 articles).**

### Solution for *all* sets of fruits

There is a way to reach all solutions very quickly. We start by factoring into primes the total, then we find few solutions through brute force. From there we can change the set of fruits with equal total. Eg., we exchange 1 orange for 1 apple and 1 pear with prices = (1,2,3). This way we can *navigate* through solutions without having to go through brute force.

**Algorithm(s):** you factorize in prime numbers the total, then you split them into two or more groups; let's take 2 groups: let A be one common multiplier, and let B the other(s). Then you can add your fruits to reach the total B.

**Examples:**

Day 1: Apple = 1, Pears = 2, Oranges = 3, Basket Value = 217

Day 2: Apple = 2, Pears = 3, Oranges = 5, Basket Value = 348

- 217 factorizes into [7, 31], we pick 31 as A (common multiplier), then let say 7=3*2+1 (2 orange, 0 pear, 1 apple), you got an answer: 62 oranges, 0 pears, 31 apples. 62+31<100: valid.
- 348 factorizes into [2, 2, 3, 29], you have several ways to
  group your factors and multiply your fruits inside this. The
  multiplier can be 29, (or 2*29 etc), then you pick your fruits to reach 12. Let's say 12=2*2+3+5. You got (2 apples, 1 pear, 1 orange) * 29, but it's more than 100 articles. You can fuse recursively 1 apple and 1 pear into 1 orange until you are below 100 articles, or you can go directly with the solution with a minimum of articles: (2 oranges, 1 apple)*29 = (58 oranges, 29 apples). And at last:

  -- 87<100 valid;

  -- the change is (-4 oranges, -2 apples), 6/93=6.45% <10% change: valid.

### Code

**Remark: no implementation of the 10% variation**

**Remark: I didn't implement the "fruit exchange" process that allows the "solution navigation"**

Run with `python -O solution.py` to optimize and remove the debug messages.

```
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors

def possibilities(value, prices):
    for i in range(0, value + 1, prices[0]):
        for j in range(0, value + 1-i, prices[1]):
            k = value - i - j
            if k % prices[2] == 0:
                yield i//prices[0], j//prices[1], k//prices[2]

days = [
    (217, (1, 2, 3)),
    (348, (2, 3, 5)),
    (251, (1, 2, 4)),
    (213, (1, 2, 3)),
]

for set in days:
    total = set[0]
    (priceApple, pricePear, priceOrange) = set[1]

    factors = prime_factors(total)
    if __debug__:
        print(str(total) + " -> " + str(factors))

    # remove small article to help factorize (odd helper)
    evenHelper = False
    if len(factors) == 1 :
        evenHelper = True
        t1 = total - priceApple
        factors = prime_factors(t1)
        if __debug__:
            print(str(total) + " --> " + str(factors))

    # merge factors on left
    while factors[0] < priceOrange :
        factors = [factors[0] * factors[1]] + factors[2:]
        if __debug__:
            print("merging: " + str(factors))

    # merge factors on right
    if len(factors) > 2:
        multiplier = 1
        for f in factors[1:]:
            multiplier *= f
        factors = [factors[0]] + [multiplier]

    (smallTotal, multiplier) = factors
    if __debug__:
        print("final factors: " + str(smallTotal) + " (small total) , " + str(multiplier) + " (multiplier)")

    # solutions satisfying #<100
    smallMax = 100 / multiplier
    solutions = [o for o in possibilities(smallTotal, set[1]) if sum(o) < smallMax ]
    for solution in solutions:
        (a,p,o) = [i * multiplier for i in solution]

        # if we used it, we need to add back the odd helper to reach the actual solution
        if evenHelper:
            a += 1

        print(str(a) + " apple(s), " + str(p) + " pear(s), " + str(o) + " orange(s)")


    # separating solutions
    print()
```

I timed the program with a 10037 total with (5, 8, 17) prices, and maximum 500 articles: it's about 2ms (on i7 6700k). The "solution navigation" process is very simple and shouldn't add significant time.

**There might be a heuristic to go from day to day without having to do the factorization + navigation + validation process. I'll think about it.**

Comment: I have ***no*** idea how you reached the notions 1) lower #articles is better 2) factoring the totals is related to solutions 3) the example baskets quoted are lowest #. Try with *as many priciest items as possible*: day1: 72*3 + 1 (73); day2: 69*5 + 3 (70) - total change 4%ish.

Comment: 1: we want to reach a solution with "#articles<100", the one with lowest #articles after refactoring is the best since the check "is #articles<100 true ?" will more likely succeed, hence reduce complexity for first solution. We can give other criterions, "best" would change.

Comment: 2: it's clear. I let you think about it.

Comment: 3: it's true after refactoring, it's not sure it's true if we consider all solutions. I may think about it.

Comment: @Soleil This isn’t completely clear to me.  Do you have an example applied to the problem? I partly understand but it’s easier for me to run the python code and play with it.

Comment: @Lostsoul I added the code. I didn't implement the 10% satisfaction search/optimization, but I think it will help understand. Please try with big numbers of fruits, it should scale fine.

Comment: I did few benchmarks. My solution is **ultrafast**, and most of the time is spent on display (`print`). I tried a 10037 total with (5, 8, 17) prices, and maximum 500 articles: it's about 2ms.

Comment: @Lostsoul I edited my answer, which actually gives all solutions. I guess we have a win here.

Comment: It took me time to understand your approach. Finally, I got it. The idea of factoring the total is very straight logical and very good one.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late, but I thought this was an interesting problem and that I might as well add my two cents.

My code:

```
import math

prices = [1, 2, 3]
basketVal = 217
maxFruits = 100
numFruits = len(prices)


## Get the possible baskets
def getPossibleBaskets(maxFruits, numFruits, basketVal, prices):

    possBaskets = []
    for i in range(101):
        for j in range(101):
            for k in range(101):

              if i + j + k > 100:
                  pass
              else:

                  possibleBasketVal = 0
                  for m in range(numFruits):
                      possibleBasketVal += (prices[m] * [i, j, k][m])

                      if possibleBasketVal > basketVal:
                          break

                  if possibleBasketVal == basketVal:
                      possBaskets.append([i, j, k])

    return possBaskets


firstDayBaskets = getPossibleBaskets(maxFruits, numFruits, basketVal, prices)
## Compare the baskets for percentage change and filter out the values
while True:

    prices = list(map(int, input("New Prices:\t").split()))
    basketVal = int(input("New Basket Value:\t"))
    maxFruits = int(input("Max Fruits:\t"))
    numFruits = len(prices)

    secondDayBaskets = getPossibleBaskets(maxFruits, numFruits, basketVal, prices)

    possBaskets = []
    for basket in firstDayBaskets:
        for newBasket in secondDayBaskets:
            if newBasket not in possBaskets:
                percentChange = 0
                for n in range(numFruits):
                    percentChange += (abs(basket[n] - newBasket[n]) / 100)
                if percentChange <= 10:
                    possBaskets.append(newBasket)

    firstDayBaskets = possBaskets
    secondDayBaskets = []

    print(firstDayBaskets)
```

I guess this could be called a brute force solution, but it definitely works. Every day, it'll print the possible configurations of the basket.